# Edit object data in IBM Cloud Object Storage or skip the first few rows when reading data

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, cloud-object-storage

How to edit object data in IBM Cloud Object Storage or skip the first few rows when reading data.

I want to edit my files on IBM COS by using API directly, do we have any API can help to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by edit? You can retrieve the object and store it (back). It is the S3 interface.

Comment: Hi @data_henrik 
Thanks for your feedback, I mean can we directly modify the content of the object using the API? Just like I upload an excel file, and then I want to delete a certain line of this excel file by calling API. I do not know if we have this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I got a new way to read COS data if you want to skip first row in COS file, you can use SKIPROWS to skip row by create EXTERNAL table.

```
SELECT *
FROM EXTERNAL 'data.csv'
    (COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(60 OCTETS), COLUMN_2 VARCHAR(60 OCTETS))
USING (
    delimiter ','
    ***SKIPROWS 1***
    s3(
        's3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud',
        'access_key_id',
        'secret_access_key',
        'bucket_name'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [S3 API for Object Storage, including the IBM Cloud Object Storage (COS)](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cos/cos-compatibility), has the concepts of bucket and object. The smallest level is object manipulation in a sense of uploading, downloading or deleting an object. Every file is an abstract object.

Thus, you cannot edit a spreadsheet or modify a video using that S3 API.

Comment: I remember that COS supports `edit line`. I don’t know if editing lines can meet our requirement, but I forgot where I saw it. Do we have relevant APIs? Thanks!